# Working from home in Vermont as W2 employee for employer in California. Need I file a CA tax return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, california, state-income-tax

I work for a company registered in CA; they have no offices in my state.  I'm a W2 employee and they are withholding taxes for VT, where I reside.  Will I need to file a CA income tax return?

This link seems to contradict itself: http://www.taxes.ca.gov/Income_Tax/newind.shtml#FilingRequired

Comment: Have you been to California?

Comment: It will depend a lot on whether you ever physically worked in California, even for short stretches of time.

Comment: @JohnFx No, I won't be working in CA.  Its a small company and everyone works from home.

Comment: Just checking, even home based employees sometimes travel to the home base a few times a year. That might change the answer.

Comment: What's confusing you in that link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

California is not one of the states that have a "Connivence of Employer" rules that would force a non-resident (telecommuter) to pay state income tax

As of 2013, only New York, Pennsylvania, Delware, and Nebraska have these laws.

If you spent a portion of the year physically working in CA, that would change things, but not for a 100% telecommute situation